# Add function to built-in class using inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a IsImage property that I wrote myself to the HttpPostedFile class, so that if a user is uploading a file, I can do something like this:

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.IsImage
```

How can I do that in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for that purpose.

```
public static class HttpPostedFileExtension
{
    public static bool IsImage(this HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        /*your method code goes here*/
    }
}
```